# How to clean Defo virus in the MBR sector?

Tags: windows-7, virus

I have Defo *(Virus DEFO.MBR)* virus in the MBR sector which Eset Antivirus can detect but its unable to clean even MBAM and Spybot are unable to find it. Any way that I can get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this and I found a few sites that talk about this virus.

First off you might just need to rewrite the MBR from what I am reading about Defo but either way here are some links to remove this.

http://threatinfo.trendmicro.com/vinfo/virusencyclo/default5.asp?VName=DEFO.A-P&VSect=P

http://vil.nai.com/vil/content/v_160134.htm

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/122221

http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?wpid=1&front_id=12  <- if you want to scan the system for malware or viruses this is the best thing you can do and works wonders

Comment: If it is a custom MBR like Dell, HP and others have, rewriting the MBR will Break advanced functionality like Factory restore and hardware diagnostics that are accessed during boot.

Answer (score 1):

Make this F-Secure rescue CD, boot from it and clean the infected MBR

http://www.techmixer.com/free-f-secure-rescue-bootable-cd-to-clean-virus-and-malware/